# If $f'/f=g'/g$ at every $1/n$ then $f=kg$ for some complex number $k$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic in domain $D$, $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ never vanish at any $z\in D$ and that 
>    $$ \frac{f'(z_n)}{f(z_n)}=\frac{g'(z_n)}{g(z_n)} $$ at a sequence  of points $\{z_n\}$ converging to $z_0\in D$. Show that $f=Kg$ for some $K\in \mathbb{C}$.

**My Solution:**

As $f,g$ are analytic in $D$ and none of them have any zero in $D$ implies $\frac{f'}{f}$ and $\frac{g'}{g}$ are also analytic on $D$. As $\frac{f'(z_n)}{f(z_n)}=\frac{g'(z_n)}{g(z_n)}$ and $z_n\to z_0
\in D$, using the identity theorem, $\frac{f'}{f}\equiv \frac{g'}{g}$ on $D$. 
Now, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)},\ \forall\ z\in D.
\end{align*}
Solving this differential equation gives me $f=Kg$ for some $K\in \mathbb{C}$. Now my question is after doing the integration we will get $\log(f)=\log(Kg)$, is it valid in the complex logarithm?

Comment: When you integrate, you can pick any branch of the log you want.  If you use the equality for two different branches of the log, you get the claim.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How do you define $\log$? Every non-zero complex number has infinitely many logarithms…

You can prove that $\frac fg$ is constant proving that its derivative is $0$:\begin{align}\left(\frac fg\right)'&=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}\\&=\frac fg\times\left(\frac{f'}f-\frac{g'}g\right)\\&=0.\end{align}